# One particular click function not working in any version of IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have several click function on one page, all fire in IE, except for one. It also only happens in IE, Firefox and Chrome are just fine.

The website can be seen on here (It's the Footer that doesn't work, it should show a popup witha  video): http://sealection.info/

```
$('#footer').click(function() {

    event.preventDefault();

    $('.splash').stop().delay(200).fadeIn('300');
    $('.splashcontent').stop().delay(400).fadeIn('300');

    $('.overlay').stop().fadeOut('300');

    $('#vimeo_frame').attr('src', 'http://player.vimeo.com/video/22659728?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;autoplay=1');

});
```

Comment: In any case `$('#footer').click(function() { event.preventDefault(); });` shouldn't you be telling it what `event` is? `$('#footer').click(function(event)...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 $('#footer').click(function(event) {

   event.preventDefault();
   .....
```

Answer (score 0):

You have exception there:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

event is not defined

Comment: Doesn't IE provide `event` as a property of `window`? (In IE it won't have a `preventDefault()` method though.)

Comment: There should be event parameter in function declaration I guess